# Maximo table control how to process the data of that session

Tags: javascript, customization, maximo

[TIMESHHET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aROqV.jpg)

Hello,

I developed an application with main custom object "ZZAMSTIMECARD"
I have a table control with columns has an attributes of ZZAMSTIMECARD.
Now, any changes done on any attributes (column) it will be saved directly on clicking "Save" button.

My question is if the user select multiple records , how do I know which record is selected in the automation script ? and how do I know which column (attribute) is modified ?

Thanks in advance

always I m getting error.